# Rounding a floating point number to an increment of another floating number, and getting the result with minimal numerical precision error

Tags: c, ieee-754

The standard ways to accomplish this create more numerical precision error than is necessary. For example:

```
double value = 20.3123;
double increment = 0.000000000000000000000001;
double value_rounded = std::floor(value/increment) * increment;
```

Here, `value_rounded` does not have the exact same bit pattern as `value`. In other words, `value_rounded` has numerical precision error and doesn't represent the closest floating point value (according to IEEE 754) to the original `20.3123` (which, in this case, was already rounded, although my question applies if it was unrounded).

Is there a way to do the rounding such that `value_rounded` is indeed the closest possible floating point value, according to IEEE 754? This would be theoretically possible given certain machine code instructions, but I'm not sure if such instructions exist.

Comment: You have tagged this C but used C++ code (`std::floor`).

Comment: Your question is not clear. In the format commonly used for `double`, the two representable values nearest 20.3123 are 20.312299999999996913402355858124792575836181640625 and 20.31230000000000046611603465862572193145751953125. In a good C implementation, `value` will be set to the latter, since it is closer to 20.3123. This **cannot** be rounded to be a multiple of 0.000000000000000000000001 (which would be 20.3123) since 20.3123 is not representable.

Comment: The value of increment is messing with the significand. Apparently, this is not precisely reversible through division/multiplication. It's probably unreasonable to expect it to be...

Comment: It is also not clear whether you are trying to round to a multiple of 0.000000000000000000000001 or to a multiple of `increment`, which is set to 0.000000000000000000000000999999999999999923700499551702824631300061898481408826917069364976185796844987407894222997128963470458984375 by a good C implementation. If you are trying to round it to a multiple of  0.000000000000000000000001, you are not going to be able to do that in the `double` format alone. What are you trying to do?

Comment: For the computation you're doing not to lose information requires  on its face at least 24 decimal digits of precision. You're computing 1*10^23 * 2*10^1 and then truncating. Doubles have at most 17.   If your problem needs that kind of precision, you'll need bigger numbers.

Comment: @Fe2O3 "0.000000000000000000000005; ( or something representable as a power of 2)" is unclear as 0.000000000000000000000005 is not representable as a power of 2 and so not any better than 0.000000000000000000000001.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do the rounding such that `value_rounded` is indeed the closest possible floating point value, according to IEEE 754?

To do rounding to closest, better to use `round()` than `floor()`.

`20.3123, 0.000000000000000000000001` are not exactly encodable `double`.  Instead [nearby values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848566/rounding-a-floating-point-number-to-an-increment-of-another-floating-number-and/73849686#comment130399139_73848566) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848566/rounding-a-floating-point-number-to-an-increment-of-another-floating-number-and/73849686#comment130399125_73848566)) are used.  No *exact* negative power-of-ten possible.

`value/increment` incurs a rounded quotient.  `... * increment` incurs a rounded product.

Code is creating a pretty good result, it is just that the expectations are wrong.  The `double` used for 0.000000000000000000000001 is *not* a power-of-ten so the result that *should* happen is not based on powers-of-ten math.

To accomplish OP's implied *decimal* goal, either:

- A decimal FP type is needed.
- About 2x precision FP type needed.
- or a whole lot of code.

If another approach is taken and code uses the decimal inverse or `1.0e24` (which is almost *exactly* encodable a `double` - need 7 more bits) with OP-like code, better results may be achieved, yet still edge cases will fail.

When `long double` affords more precision:

```
long double pow10 = 1.0e24L;
double value_rounded = (double) (roundl(value * pow10) / pow10);
```